# what are the differences between different Sygic map types?

Tags: gps, sygic, sygic-mobile-sdk, sygic-maps

There are three different maps for sygic gps navigation: NT or TA or OS maps.

I am wondering what are their differences? which one I should use?

Comment: are you asking abour sygic mobile sdk https://www.sygic.com/developers/mobile-sdk/introduction or sygic maps https://www.sygic.com/developers/maps-api-services/introduction ?

Answer (score 3):

those are different map providers:

- NT = NAVTEQ (currently Here) https://wego.here.com/
- TA = TeleAtlas (currently TomTom) https://mydrive.tomtom.com/
- OS = OpenStreetMap - free crowsourced maps https://www.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: "which one I should use?"

Comment: you need no license for OS map, that is free (but the quality of map data corresponds with this price :) ). at beginning i recommend OS maps, later you can switch to NT or TA, when you decide after analyzing license policies

Answer (score 0):

These acronyms stand for map providers. NT is for [Navteq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navteq), TA is for [Tele Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tele_Atlas) and OS or OSM are [Open Street Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap)

They all have slightly different coverage quality depending on a region.